# MemoryError when trying to concat huge dataframes from read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, out-of-memory, concatenation

I have a large data set which contains approximate 109G data which are separated into 245 .vsc.gz files. I tried to open each of them and then join all of them. The first step is OK I successfully achieved what I want but later when I try to concat them I received the following error.`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CleanDataVR2.py", line 92, in <module>
    df_concated = pd.concat(dl)
  File "/share/apps/anaconda/2/2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 835, in concat
    return op.get_result()
  File "/share/apps/anaconda/2/2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 1025, in get_result
    concat_axis=self.axis, copy=self.copy)
  File "/share/apps/anaconda/2/2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4474, in concatenate_block_managers
    for placement, join_units in concat_plan]
  File "/share/apps/anaconda/2/2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4579, in concatenate_join_units
    concat_values = com._concat_compat(to_concat, axis=concat_axis)
  File "/share/apps/anaconda/2/2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py", line 2741, in _concat_compat
    return np.concatenate(to_concat, axis=axis)
MemoryError
```

And then is my code.

```
dl= []
dtype_dict= {'#RIC': 'str', 'Date[G]':'str', 'Time[G]':'str', 'Price': 'float16', 'Volume': 'float16'}

for f in file_list:
    df=pd.read_csv(f, compression='gzip',header=0, sep=',', 
               quotechar='"',usecols= 
               ['#RIC','Date[G]','Time[G]','Price','Volume'],
               dtype=dtype_dict,low_memory=False)
    df= df.dropna(subset=['Price']) 
    df['Tage'] = df['Volume'].map(volume_filter)
    dl.append(df)
df_concated = pd.concat(dl)
```

That function named `volume_filter`is just a function I wrote to get the column named `Tage`. Since this part works well I didn't put it here. Each data frames have the same structure as follow.

```
            #RIC      Date[G]       Time[G]    Price  Volume   Tage
0         URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:19:46.800   45.000   152.0   T200
8         URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:28:53.769   45.000  2848.0  T3000
9         URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:28:53.769   45.000  1725.0  T2000
11        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:28:53.844   45.000   427.0   T500
13        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:28:53.898   45.000   450.0   T500
15        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:28:53.981   45.000   200.0   T200
20        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:28:54.124   45.000   850.0   T900
21        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:28:54.124   45.000  1073.0  T2000
24        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:28:54.329   45.000   200.0   T200
25        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:28:54.617   44.965   310.0   T400
26        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:28:54.617   44.965   310.0   T400
29        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:29:04.522   45.025   620.0   T700
30        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:29:04.769   45.025   620.0   T700
31        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:30:21.974   45.000  2800.0  T3000
32        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:30:21.974   45.000   700.0   T700
35        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:30:22.036   45.000   679.0   T700
39        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:30:22.110   45.000   200.0   T200
40        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:30:22.114   45.000   250.0   T300
42        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:30:22.405   45.025   243.0   T300
43        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:30:22.663   45.025   243.0   T300
44        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:30:23.737   45.000  2550.0  T3000
47        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:30:23.769   45.000  1500.0  T2000
51        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:30:23.769   44.920   200.0   T200
52        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:30:23.856   44.900   150.0   T200
54        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:30:25.101   45.000  1901.0  T2000
56        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:30:25.145   44.900   650.0   T700
58        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:30:25.145   44.900   200.0   T200
64        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:30:37.648   44.950   195.0   T200
65        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:30:37.829   44.950   195.0   T200
68        URKAq.L  01-SEP-2008  11:30:47.743   44.950  1031.0  T2000
```

I tried one solution of @B. M.

```
def byhand(dfs):
    mtot=0
    with open('df_all.bin','wb') as f:
        for df in dfs:
            m,n =df.shape
            mtot += m
            f.write(df.values.tobytes())
            typ=df.values.dtype                
    #del dfs
    with open('df_all.bin','rb') as f:
        buffer=f.read()
        data=np.frombuffer(buffer,dtype=typ).reshape(mtot,n)
        df_all=pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=list(range(n))) 
    os.remove('df_all.bin')
    return df_all
```

But I still got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CleanDataVR2.py", line 107, in <module>
    byhand(dl)
  File "CleanDataVR2.py", line 102, in byhand
    data=np.frombuffer(buffer,dtype=typ).reshape(mtot,n)
ValueError: cannot create an OBJECT array from memory buffer
```

Right now I'm really confused. I have run my own code with 2 files in a supercomputer and everthing is fun. Why I there is an error with more files? Plus I have used 5*256GB memory which should be enough.

Comment: @B. M. Can your help with this question? Thank you.

Comment: Do you actually need to keep them all in-memory at the same time? Also, **you need to specify each column's dtypes to `pd.read_csv`** otherwise you will read every column as a string instead of (converting immediately at read-time) as a date, time, or float, which will waste Gigabytes. **Please focus on improving your `pd.read_csv` command on just one file, to aggressively reduce memory usage to the absolute minimum.** Then post your revised code in the question. Also, looks like `Volume` is an integer, not float.

Comment: And you can avoid more memory waste instead of the line `df =  df[['#RIC','Date[G]','Time[G]','Price','Volume']]`. Just directly use [`pd.read_csv(..., usecols)` argument](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to only ever read in the subset of columns you want; and use `dtypes` argument to only directly read them as the intended dtype, not gigabytes of unneeded string.

Comment: Please **read the [`pd.read_csv()` doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)** and understand which of its many options reduce your memory usage.

Comment: Test all this by reading in say the first 1,000 lines of one single file, and keep aggressively reducing its memory usage, until you can't do any better.

Comment: @smci Hi thanks for your advice. I just edit my code as you suggested. Is it better now? Please feel free to point out any stupid mistake I made. I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Ok the read_csv line looks better. Please just read one single file, then 
 use `df.describe()` or else for more in-depth memory usage, by column: `print df.memory_usage(index=False, deep=True) / df.shape[0]`. **Post us the outputs of those, and let's figure out if your file size has any unexplained bloat.** (For example, do any columns have any unwanted NA values, strings or objects? rather than builtin types.) Before you start `concat`ing multiple files.

Comment: For example, you should not be reading in 'Date[G]' and 'Time[G]' columns as strings, you should convert them directly into a datetime object at read-time, see the [`pd.read_csv` doc for date/time-parsing arguments](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Fail that, `read_csv(... chunksize=....)` to read in chunks  then do datetime conversion on each chunk, before concat'ting them.

Comment: @smci I tried to set 'Date[G]' and 'Time[G]'  into date time with chunk but the code runs really slow compared to I set them as strings. Beside this. Price and Volume columns do have NA value and drop them as my code shows. I tried to do that with chunk but, the same problem, it runs really slow than the existing code.

Comment: I recommended convert 'Date[G]' and 'Time[G]' **columns directly at read-time** (not afterwards, on a chunk) into a datetime object at read-time, see the [`pd.read_csv` doc for date/time-parsing arguments](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). You didn't do that. Also, show us some timings for reading file (with and without chunksize), and post us the memory size: the outputs of `df.describe()` and `print df.memory_usage(index=False, deep=True) / df.shape[0]`. Just for one file, so we can debug.